# How can I alternate between 2 players in a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am taking a computer science class and our first project in Python (turtle) is a little Tic-Tac-Toe game. The project is nearly complete BUT I am struggling to figure out how to alternate between 2 players, please bare with me on how I approached this as I am still learning.

I tried using a variable that would be used for a for loop, where the value was equal to 0 and then every time a player would move it would add +1 to the value, therefore in theory, everytime they moved, it would add 1 and then the for loop would be not be true, then switching to the other for loop for the other player. I now realize that none of that makes any sense and wouldn't have worked. Here's what that looked like:

```
if current_player == "o" or current_player == "O":
    while current_player == "o" or current_player == "O":
        alternate_turn = 0
        while alternate_turn == 0:
            user_input = int(input("Type in a number where O would like to move: "))
            if user_input == 1 :
                goto(-134,140)
                alternate_turn = alternate_turn + 1
```

everytime I ran this, it would just crash. So I now I am stuck with what I had started off with originally:

```
#If the user said "x", code checks for to see if true then runs commands for "x"
if current_player == "x" or current_player == "X" :
    while current_player == "x" or current_player == "X":
        user_input = int(input("Type in a number where X would like to move: "))

#If user said "o", code checks to see if true then runs commands for "o"
if current_player == "o" or current_player == "O":
    while current_player == "o" or current_player == "O":
        user_input = int(input("Type in a number where O would like to move: "))
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
#Ask user for input on who goes first
user_select = (input("Who is playing first?(X or O?): "))

#Whatever the user said for user_select, it is stored as the current_player
current_player = user_select

#If the user said "x", code checks for to see if true then runs following commands
if current_player == "x" or current_player == "X" :
    while current_player == "x" or current_player == "X":
        user_input = int(input("Type in a number where X would like to move: "))
#If user said "o", code checks to see if true then runs commands for "o"
if current_player == "o" or current_player == "O":
    while current_player == "o" or current_player == "O":
        user_input = int(input("Type in a number where O would like to move: "))
```

I am very unsure on what to do next. I have tried looking at other solutions, however, none of them seemed to work for my code (Maybe because they weren't meant for my code). What I am trying to achieve is when it asks for input from either "X" or "O", either one of them will type in a number where they will move, and then it will go onto the next player, and then after that do the same until it is either a draw or someone wins. I am open to any way of solving this because the deadline is this Friday. Thank you and I apologize if my post is a little unclear as this is my first time posting.

Comment: Please share a [mcve], as well as the error message that's displayed when the program crashes. Could you not use the `current_player` variable and assign it to `"x"` when it's the X player's turn, then once X moves, assign it to `"o"` and vice versa? `alternate_turn` seems like it's sort of trying to achieve that, but seems like extra state. The technically best way to do this (probably out of scope for you) is keeping a [ply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ply_(game_theory)).

Comment: I added the reproducible example, and I will try what you suggested in the morning as right now it is very late. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, that's a step forward, but if you check the out the link I shared, the code should be fully runnable and complete, without any extra information (like irrelevant drawings or images that distract from the core issue). All variables and imports should be there. You might also want to look into making the grid clickable for moves, or at least allowing users to enter their move [via the GUI](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput), rather than making them use the terminal (but I understand it may be a contrived app for learning sake).

Comment: Regarding your code, I think you're missing a main game loop, something like `while game_active: if current_player == "o": <do O move stuff> else: <do X move stuff>`. If the logic is more or less the same for both players, you may not even need the branch. Part of the answer depends on how you're representing the game/board state, and if you haven't coded that yet, I'd start with that, and add input at the very end. You can test the game logic by hardcoding in a series of moves to avoid having to worry about it initially.

Answer (score 1):

At no point in the loop do you change the player. Also, you do not need the loop.

If you are going to do this:

```
user_select = input("Who is playing first?(X or O?): ")
```

Then do this instead. Notice that we mostly don't care about "x" and "o". We care about `current_player`, and we have 2 distinct players in the 2 player game.

```
player_one = input("Who is playing first?(X or O?): ").lower()
player_two = 'xo'[player_one == 'x']

current_player = player_one

#game loop
while True:
    user_input = int(input(f"Type in a number where {current_player} would like to move: "))

    #ultra-basic way to switch players
    if current_player == player_one:
        current_player = player_two
    else:
        current_player = player_one
```

If you want to be a bit clever and get rid of all the conditions, you could use a `deque` to rotate players. Every time you rotate the next player will become the zero index of `players`.

```
from collections import deque

player_one = input("Who is playing first?(X or O?): ").lower()
player_two = 'xo'[player_one == 'x']
players    = deque((player_one,player_two))

#game loop
while True:
    current_player = players[0]

    user_input = int(input(f"Type in a number where {current_player} would like to move: "))

    players.rotate(1)
```